# NUnit3TestExecutor throwing an ArgumentNullException - Value cannot be null

Tags: azure-devops, nunit

I am using Azure DevOps for our CI/CD pipeline.
The Visual Studio Test task on the Agent Job has suddenly started failing.

The error in the logs is:

> An exception occurred while invoking executor
> 'executor://nunit3testexecutor/': Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'type')

- No changes have been made to the pipeline.
- No changes have been made to the source code.
- However something *might* have changed on the build server (I don't know yet).

The task is defined as follows:

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*Tests.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
     !**\bin\**\ref\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'FullyQualifiedName!~XXX.IntegrationTests'
    otherConsoleOptions: '/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0"'
```

I have had a look at the `NUnit3TestExecutor` [source code](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/blob/master/src/NUnitTestAdapter/NUnit3TestExecutor.cs) but I can't see a method with a parameter called 'type'.

The only place I can this parameter is in the `System.Attribute` (CoreCLR) class which NUnitAttribute inherits from:

```
public static Attribute[] GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type type, bool inherit)
{
    ...

    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    ...
}
```

Is there a reason why the test executor would suddenly start failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by modifying the Azure Pipeline to clean the build directories.

Go to: Pipeline > Get sources > Clean options

Set this to value 'All build directories'.